# jQuery get div#contentRow height

Tags: 2013, jquery

I try to show and hide a custom footer on a SharePoint 2013, depending if we reach the bottom of the page or not. To do this, I need to calculate the total height of the div with the id `contentRow`.

I referenced jQuery and my custom javascript file into the master page. It load well.

If the **contentRow** height is lesser than the height of the viewport of the web browser (it means no or a little vertical scrollbar) + the scrolling index, I show by default the footer.

**Issue** : For some pages it succeed to find the height property, but most of the pages have their div height found to `0px` at page load/refresh. So the effect is the footer shown even if the page can be scrolled down, even if it shouldn't.

I do this with this piece of code :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    console.log($("div#contentRow").height());
    // if the content Row height is lesser or equal to the viewport height + the scrolled position
    if ($("div#contentRow").height() <= $(window).height() + $("div#s4-workspace").scrollTop()) 
    {
        $('#footermsg').slideDown('slow');  //show footer
    }
});
```

I suspect the div#contentRow height to haven't been calculated before the script verify this condition, because the `$("div#contentRow").height()` is showing 0 in the console log.
I also tried into the `$(document).ready(...` function, with a delay, into the `$("div#...).load(...` function, etc ... no result.

I tested it on Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Try to delay your script the SharePoint way i.e. use `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);`. Have a look at example in [SP.ClientContext object (sp.js)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245759.aspx)

Comment: I tried to do so, I see that the function sharePointReady works, but my height after this is still 0px for my div. But when I scroll, I see the height is not to 0 (I've put a console.log of the height in a on("scroll") event)

Comment: Moreover it not seems to be a viable solution as sometimes, at page refresh, the function is not called for some reason ... seems random, depending on the loading charge.

Answer (score 0):

One dirty way would be to use a setTimeout (with a short delay) and then apply your functions. I used it to hide a few elements and it works, but there must be another way.

Comment: I tried a timeOut, but it won't works, even if I put a 5 seconds timer before executing my test. I'm near of the depression lol

Comment: Can you show me your code please ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { 
 console.log("Document is ready");
 //_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('defaultVisibility');              
 setTimeout(defaultVisibility, 2000); 
   
 function defaultVisibility() {
  
  if (isInIframe == false) {
   if ($("div#contentRow").height() +  $("div#s4-titlerow").height() <= $(window).height() + $("div#s4-workspace").scrollTop() - $("div.ms-cui-ribbonTopBars").height()*2) 
       {
        $('#footermsg').slideDown('slow');
       }
     }
 }`

Comment: For better readability, I'd say that you should use variables :) however, I don't see anything wrong in the code. Have you also tried console.log outside your conditions to see if the function is actually launched ? FYI, I also tried the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames and never succeeded, unfortunately ...

Comment: Yeah, and I followed the instructions on a site where the author actually claims that he succeeded. wierd ... yeh sorry for the visibility, I was in mode "code monkey"

Comment: What about the console.log ?

Comment: I can clearly see that the function is launched with the 2 sec delay ... So the property seems to be never filled with another value than 0. It's sad, but my SharePoint environement maybe have something to do in it.

Comment: So even with the timeout the property value doesn't change ? that's weird ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding the function to _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames object as such:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('functionName');
function functionName(){...}
```

Comment: I visited the following blog http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/ and it appears to be a good practice to load in SP body the function to use jQuery methods. However, I can't make it work. Here is what I've tested in my custom js file :

`$.getScript("/sites/archimen/_layouts/15/sp.js");

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('defaultVisibility');

function defaultVisibility() {
   console.log("test");
}`

Nothing appears in the console at sharepoint load page ... Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure why that wouldn't work unless the custom script you have somehow isn't present on the page. Are you using a content editor web part? Also, you shouldn't have to load sp.js for the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames array to be present.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm referencing my custom script into the master page. It's loaded because for the others functionalities it does what I want.

Comment: What happens when you add a content editor web part to a page and add `<script type="text/javascript">console.log(JSON.stringify(_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames));</script>`

Does anything appear in the console when you do this?

Comment: It appears that I got a syntax error when inserting this code into a web page. So it freeze the page and I cannot modify it anymore.